# Remote control switch for RC planes

Tags: switches, relay, remote-control

could someone please explain why is needed to connect common grounds on rc switch. I am trying to understand inner working of this device and why connection with the ground has not been done internally.

[image]

Device is called Turnigy RC switch and documentation is provided here: [enter link description here](https://hobbyking.com/media/file/t/u/turnigy_rc_switch_manual.pdf)

Comment: Rather than just close this, let's close it as a duplicate of a question that explains the concept of a common ground, in a functionally similar (even if superficially different) application.

Comment: Common ground in this question is not relevant to "general" common ground sense, but what would be the circuit behind this switch that would need common ground to exist in this particular case. Answer you are relating to is not answer to my question sir.

Comment: You are mistaken, it is the same - it would be so for almost any internal circuit, at least one able to control an arbitrary-motor like load wired in the manner shown, which means there is no other way to get a common ground. And with your question only one vote short of closing, it is the most useful response you are likely to get.